# Ubuntu 20.10 very slow performance

Tags: laptop

I made a clean install of Ubuntu 20.10 in my laptop and I see that it is extremely slow.

My laptop is HP 250 G5 with Intel HD graphics. It has SSD disk, I don't have a swap partition and my RAM is 8GB.

What can I do?

Comment: You should investigate further before asking a question. Is it related to memory, CPU, network, or disk? Are there any specific processes that make your computer slow?

Comment: There may be some pointers [here](https://linuxhint.com/improve_ssd_performance_linux_laptops/) for you investigate.

Comment: Can you try installing `htop` with: `sudo apt install htop -y` and running it in your terminal with just the command `htop`. It would be helpful if you post a screenshot here just to see.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? When you say slow is it boot time or always slow?

Comment: thanks everyone. I dont know if its related to memory, cpu or disk. My laptop works very smmoth windows 10, and its was alsovery smmoth with ubuntu 20.04 when i have clean installed it when it came out. Use24601 your answer does not apply to my problem because my laptop is almost always plugged in to the power supply. Joseph my laptop is always extremely slow.

Comment: here is a screenshot of htop https://imgur.com/a/W8pXmg0

Comment: any answer could be helpful